# Render FFmpeg AVFrame as OpenGL texture?

Tags: c++, opengl, ffmpeg

I'm attempting to to render a jpeg image (1024x1024 pixels) in the form of an FFmpeg AVFrame as a texture in OpenGL. What I get instead is something that appears as a 1024x1024 dark green quad:

[image: dark green quad screenshot]

The code to render the AVFrame data in OpenGL is shown below. I have convinced myself that the raw RGB data held within the FFmpeg AVFrame data is not solely dark green.

```
GLuint g_texture = {};

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
void display()
{
    // Clear color and depth buffers
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);     // Operate on model-view matrix

    glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    GLuint texture = g_texture;
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture);

    // Draw a quad
    glBegin(GL_QUADS);
    glVertex2i(0, 0); // top left
    glVertex2i(1024, 0); // top right
    glVertex2i(1024, 1024); // bottom right
    glVertex2i(0, 1024); // bottom left
    glEnd();

    glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);

    glFlush();
}

/* Initialize OpenGL Graphics */
void initGL(int w, int h)
{
    glViewport(0, 0, w, h); // use a screen size of WIDTH x HEIGHT
    glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);     // Enable 2D texturing

    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);     // Make a simple 2D projection on the entire window
    glOrtho(0.0, w, h, 0.0, 0.0, 100.0);
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);    // Set the matrix mode to object modeling
    //glTranslatef( 0, 0, -15 );

    glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
    glClearDepth(0.0f);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT); // Clear the window
}

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    std::shared_ptr<AVFrame> apAVFrame;
    if (!load_image_to_AVFrame(apAVFrame, "marble.jpg"))
    {
        assert(false);
        return 1;
    }

    // From here on out, the AVFrame is RGB interleaved
    // and is sized to 1,024 x 1,024 (power of 2).

    glutInit(&argc, argv);
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_RGB | GLUT_SINGLE);
    glutInitWindowSize(1060, 1060);
    glutInitWindowPosition(0, 0);
    glutCreateWindow("OpenGL - Creating a texture");

    glGenTextures(1, &g_texture);

    //glPixelStorei(GL_UNPACK_ALIGNMENT, 1);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, g_texture);
    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGB, apAVFrame->width,
                 apAVFrame->height, 0, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE,
                 apAVFrame->data[0]);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR); /* We will use linear interpolation for magnification filter */
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR); /* We will use linear interpolation for minifying filter */

    initGL(1060, 1060);

    glutDisplayFunc(display);

    glutMainLoop();

    return 0;
}
```

Environment:

- Ubuntu 18.04
- GCC v8.2

**EDIT**: As per @immibis' suggestion below, it all works when I change the rendering of the quad to:

```
// Draw a quad
glBegin(GL_QUADS);
glTexCoord2f(0, 0);
glVertex2i(0, 0); // top left
glTexCoord2f(1, 0);
glVertex2i(1024, 0); // top right
glTexCoord2f(1, 1);
glVertex2i(1024, 1024); // bottom right
glTexCoord2f(0, 1);
glVertex2i(0, 1024); // bottom left
glEnd();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to give your vertices texture coordinates, so all the pixels on your screen are reading the same pixel from the texture. (The top-left, or wherever the default texture coordinates are)

Use glTexCoord2f before glVertex2i to set the texture coordinates for the vertex. They go from 0 on the top/left of the texture, to 1 on the bottom/right, so the corners of the texture are 0,0, 1,0, 1,1 and 0,1.

Comment: Thanks. Right you are!